# Is there a way to run a cmd shortcut/batch with prefilled parameters but wait for a last one?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, youtube-dl

I'm new to both CMD and .bat files, so I am unsure which will solve my problem. I wasn't able to find a solution on my own.

Basically, I want a shortcut to run a Youtube-DL command and only have it prompt me to fill the last parameter, the URL. Here's the line I'm trying to have already filled:

```
youtube-dl --no-playlist --metadata-from-title "%(artist)s - %(title)s" -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" -x --audio-format mp3 --audio-quality 0 --add-metadata [URL should go here]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you make a search here for `prompt input`, I'm sure you will find what you need. When it comes the the command you've shown, just remember that all **`%`** characters will require doubling if it is being run from a batch file.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and for the search tips.

In case any one reads this and is wondering, the proper answer is to create a batch file and input:


    @echo off
    set /p "URL=Enter URL parameter: "
    echo %URL%
    youtube-dl --no-playlist --metadata-from-title "%%(artist)s - %%(title)s" -o "%%(title)s.%%(ext)s" -x --audio-format mp3 --audio-quality 0 --add-metadata %url%
    pause

Comment: Do not put code in comments. You can answer your own question. So please delete your comment and answer the question or delete your question.

Answer (score 0):

create a batch file with the following content:

```
@echo off
set "url=%~1"
if not defined url set /p "url=Enter URL: "
youtube-dl --no-playlist --metadata-from-title "%%(artist)s - %%(title)s" -o "%%(title)s.%%(ext)s" -x --audio-format mp3 --audio-quality 0 --add-metadata %url%
```

Name it for example `yt.bat`

You can then call it with

```
yt <url>
```

or just

```
yt
```

If you give no parameter, the script will ask you.